# ESLint reports "screen not found in @testing-library/vue"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, react-testing-library, vue-testing-library

I'm trying to use `@testing-library/vue` and import the screen method and ESLint reports the following error: `"screen not found in @testing-library/vue"`.

```js
// The render function doesn't error but screen yes
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/vue';
```

Anyone came across this issue before? I think it's due to the fact that `@testing-library/vue` re-exports `@testing-library/dom` methods but I supposed that ESLint was able to pick that up.

Answer (score 0):

Added `"@testing-library/vue"` to my `types` Array inside `tsconfig.json` and it now works.